# How to add Wordpress Admin "Insert Link" UI (searches through existing posts for URL) and functionality into a custom plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, links

When inserting a link into a post using the Wordpress Visual Editor, a popup UI shows up allowing you to type in / live search for the title of a published post.

Is there any way to allow this functionality in a custom plugin's admin area? I currently have a plugin that has a basic insert URL function, but it does not search through existing posts. Everything is manual.

Thanks!